# Create table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a JavaScript function which creates a table with 3 rows 2 cells.

Could anybody tell me how I can create the table below using my function (I need to do this for my situation)?

Here is my JavaScript and HTML code given below:

```js
function tableCreate() {
  //body reference 
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  // create elements <table> and a <tbody>
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // cells creation
  for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    // table row creation
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      // create element <td> and text node 
      //Make text node the contents of <td> element
      // put <td> at end of the table row
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell is row " + j + ", column " + i);

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    //row added to end of table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  // append the <tbody> inside the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // put <table> in the <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // tbl border attribute to 
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

This should work (from a few alterations to your code above).

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100%';
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
  var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
        break
      } else {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
        i == 1 && j == 1 ? td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2') : null;
        tr.appendChild(td)
      }
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)
}
tableCreate();
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's best to create the variables outside of the loop

Comment: @Cerbrus It is good solution but it doesn't work before IE8. Table is added to the DOM Explorer but somehow, it is not visible. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: @bdogru: Why do you need to support IE8? It's ancient. Google [dropped that browser late 2012](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2492571/web-apps/google-to-drop-support-for-ie8-on-nov--15.html)

Comment: @Cerbrus, IE8 supports, my company's client is an old bank and we must support IE5 !!! so sometimes (as this one) I need to find a workaround.

Comment: @bdogru: Then I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I finally solved the issue by changing last line as: body.innerHTML = tbl.outerHTML  it seems like appendChild updates dom structure but not rerender html view (modern browser does) but innerHTML directly affects html view.

Answer (score 162):

Slightly shorter code using [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) and [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell):

```js
function tableCreate() {
  const body = document.body,
        tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100px';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      if (i === 2 && j === 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        const td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Cell I${i}/J${j}`));
        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
          td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate();
```

Also, this doesn't use some "bad practices", such as setting a `border` attribute instead of using CSS, and it accesses the `body` through `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`;

Answer (score 23):

Originally posted on [mysamplecode.com by unknown](https://web.archive.org/web/20121219144104/https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/generate-html-table-using-javascript.html):

> ```
> function addTable() {
>   var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
>
>   var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
>   table.border = '1';
>
>   var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
>   table.appendChild(tableBody);
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>     var tr = document.createElement('TR');
>     tableBody.appendChild(tr);
>
>     for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
>       var td = document.createElement('TD');
>       td.width = '75';
>       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
>       tr.appendChild(td);
>     }
>   }
>   myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
> }
> addTable();
> ```

and the HTML:

> ```
> <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
> ```

Answer (score 14):

Here is the latest method using the `.map` function in JavaScript.
You create a table in html and then insert body with JavaScript.

```js
const data = [{Name:'Sydney', Day: 'Monday', Time: '10:00AM'},{Name:'New York', Day: 'Monday',Time: '11:00AM'},]; // any json data or array of objects

const tableData = data.map(value => {
  return (
    `<tr>
       <td>${value.Name}</td>
       <td>${value.Day}</td>
       <td>${value.Time}</td>
    </tr>`
  );
}).join('');

const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");
tableBody.innerHTML = tableData;
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Tour</th>
      <th scope="col">Day</th>
      <th scope="col">Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
                                    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" onclick="tester()"></table>
        <script>
            var student;
            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                student = {
                    name: "Name" + j,
                    rank: "Rank" + j,
                    stuclass: "Class" + j,
                };
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(j);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

                cell1.innerHTML = student.name,
                cell2.innerHTML = student.rank,
                cell3.innerHTML = student.stuclass;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Might not solve the problem described in this particular question, but might be useful to people looking to create tables out of array of objects:

```js
function createTable(objectArray, fields, fieldTitles) {
  let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  let tbl = document.createElement('table');
  let thead = document.createElement('thead');
  let thr = document.createElement('tr');
  fieldTitles.forEach((fieldTitle) => {
    let th = document.createElement('th');
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fieldTitle));
    thr.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(thr);
  tbl.appendChild(thead);

  let tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  objectArray.forEach((object) => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    fields.forEach((field) => {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object[field]));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);    
  });
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)
  return tbl;
}

createTable([
  {name: 'Banana', price: '3.04'},
  {name: 'Orange', price: '2.56'},
  {name: 'Apple', price: '1.45'}
],
['name', 'price'], ['Name', 'Price']);
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution will be perfect when you want rows and columns dynamic. You can accept rows and columns as arguments.

```
function tableCreate(row, col){
    let body = document.body;
    let tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '200px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

    for(let i = 0; i < row; i++){
        let tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(let j = 0; j < col; j++){
                let td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${i},${j}` ));
                td.style.border = '1px solid black';
            }     
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate(4,4);
```

**Output** -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">
            <b>Enter the no of row and column to create table:</b>
            <br/><br/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>No. of Row(s) </th>
                    <th>No. of Column(s)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="row" value="4" /> X</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="col" value="7" />Y</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <button id="create" onclick="create()">create table</button>
        </p>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Reload page" onclick="reloadPage()">
        <script>
            function create() {
                var row = parseInt(document.getElementById("row").value);
                var col = parseInt(document.getElementById("col").value);

                var tablestart="<table id=myTable border=1>";
                var tableend = "</table>";
                var trstart = "<tr bgcolor=#ff9966>";
                var trend = "</tr>";
                var tdstart = "<td>";
                var tdend = "</td>";
                var data="data in cell";
                var str1=tablestart + trstart + tdstart + data + tdend + trend + tableend;
                document.write(tablestart);

                for (var r=0;r<row;r++) {
                    document.write(trstart);
                    for(var c=0; c<col; c++) {
                        document.write(tdstart+"Row."+r+" Col."+c+tdend);
                    }
                }

                document.write(tableend);
                document.write("<br/>");
                var s="<button id="+"delete"+" onclick="+"deleteTable()"+">Delete top Row </button>";
                document.write(s);
                var relod="<button id="+"relod"+" onclick="+"reloadPage()"+">Reload Page </button>";
                document.write(relod);
            }
            function deleteTable() {
                var dr=0;
                if(confirm("It will be deleted..!!")) {
                    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(dr);
                }
            }
            function reloadPage(){
                location.reload();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find this helpful.

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test.css">
<body>

</body>
<script src = "test.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
var tableString = "<table>",
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    div = document.createElement('div');

for (row = 1; row < 101; row += 1) {

    tableString += "<tr>";

    for (col = 1; col < 11; col += 1) {

        tableString += "<td>" + "row [" + row + "]" + "col [" + col + "]" + "</td>";
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
}

tableString += "</table>";
div.innerHTML = tableString;
body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    body{
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(179,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
        text-align: center;
    }
    #name{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .input{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #004d00;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: cursive;
    }
    #entry{
        width: 150px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-family:  cursive;
        background-color: #001a66;
        color: whitesmoke;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        margin: 20px;
    }
    table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 50px auto;
        background-color: burlywood;
    }
    table,th,td{
       border: 2px solid black;
       padding:5px;

    }
    th{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #004d00;
    }
    td{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: crimson;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: Georgia;
    }
    .length{
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <!-- Code to get student details -->
    <div id="container" >
        <div class="input">
             Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="length" placeholder="eg: Anil Ambani"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
             Email: <input type="text" id="mail" class="length" placeholder="eg: AnilAmbani@gmail.com"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
             Phone: <input type="text" id="phn"  class="length" placeholder="eg: 9898989898"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
             SLNO: <input type="number" id="sln" class="length" placeholder="eg: 1"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button id="entry"> I/P ENTRY</button>
    </div>
    <table id="tabledata">
       <tr>
          <th> Name</th>
          <th> Email</th>
          <th> Phone</th>
          <th> Slno</th>
       </tr> 
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var entry = document.getElementById('entry');
    entry.addEventListener("click",display);
    var row = 1;
    function display(){
        var nam =  document.getElementById('name').value;
        var emal = document.getElementById('mail').value;
        var ph = document.getElementById('phn').value;
        var sl = document.getElementById('sln').value;
        var disp = document.getElementById("tabledata");
        var newRow = disp.insertRow(row);
        var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = nam;
        cell2.innerHTML = emal;
        cell3.innerHTML = ph;
        cell4.innerHTML = sl;
        row++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: create form 
name those then make a function give them a new variable with document.id
initially take row =1
inset each cell with their index places,then assign objects to the variables and increment the row

Answer (score 0):

This is how to loop through a javascript object and put the data into a table, code modified from @Vanuan's answer.

```html
<body>
    <script>
    function createTable(objectArray, fields, fieldTitles) {
      let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      let tbl = document.createElement('table');
      let thead = document.createElement('thead');
      let thr = document.createElement('tr');

      for (p in objectArray[0]){
        let th = document.createElement('th');
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p));
        thr.appendChild(th);
        
      }
     
      thead.appendChild(thr);
      tbl.appendChild(thead);

      let tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
      let tr = document.createElement('tr');
      objectArray.forEach((object) => {
        let n = 0;
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (p in objectArray[0]){
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          td.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid green");
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object[p]));
          tr.appendChild(td);
          n++;
        };
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);    
      });
      tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
      body.appendChild(tbl)
      return tbl;
    }

    createTable([
                  {name: 'Banana', price: '3.04'}, // k[0]
                  {name: 'Orange', price: '2.56'},  // k[1]
                  {name: 'Apple', price: '1.45'}
               ])
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a version that can parse through a list of objects dynamically to create the table as a string. I split it into three functions for writing the header columns, the body rows, and stitching it all together. I exported as a string for use on a server. My code uses [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to keep things elegant.

If you want to add styling (like bootstrap), that can be done by adding more html to `HEAD_PREFIX` and `HEAD_SUFFIX`.

```
// helper functions
const TABLE_PREFIX = '<div><table class="tg">';
const TABLE_SUFFIX = '</table></div>';
const TABLE_HEAD_PREFIX = '<thead><tr>';
const TABLE_HEAD_SUFFIX = '</tr></thead>';
const TABLE_BODY_PREFIX = '<tbody><tr>';
const TABLE_BODY_SUFFIX = '</tr></tbody>';

function generateTableHead(cols) {
  return `
    ${TABLE_HEAD_PREFIX}
      <td>#</td>
    ${cols.map((col) => `<td>${col}</td>`).join('')}
    ${TABLE_HEAD_SUFFIX}`;
}

function generateTableBody(cols, data) {
  return `
    ${TABLE_BODY_PREFIX}
    ${data.map((object, index) => `
        <tr><td>${index}</td>
        ${cols.map((col) => `<td>${object[col]}</td>`).join('')}
      </tr>`).join('')}
    ${TABLE_BODY_SUFFIX}`;
}

/**
 * generate an html table from an array of objects with the same values
 *
 * @param {array<string>} cols array of object columns used in order of columns on table
 * @param {array<object>} data array of objects containing data in a single depth
 */
function generateTable(data, defaultCols = false) {
  let cols = defaultCols;
  if (!cols) cols = Object.keys(data[0]); // auto generate columns if not defined
  return `
    ${TABLE_PREFIX}
    ${generateTableHead(cols)}
    ${generateTableBody(cols, data)}
    ${TABLE_SUFFIX}`;
}
```

Here's an example use:

```
const mountains = [
  { height: 200, name: "Mt. Mountain" },
  { height: 323, name: "Old Broken Top"},
]
const htmlTableString = generateTable(mountains );
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = "Create Table";
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click", createTable, true);
function createTable(){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("id", "tbl");
document.body.appendChild(div)
 document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = "<table border = '1'>" +
  '<tr>' +
    '<th>Header 1</th>' +
    '<th>Header 2</th> ' +
    '<th>Header 3</th>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>Data 1</td>' +
    '<td>Data 2</td>' +
    '<td>Data 3</td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>Data 1</td>' +
    '<td>Data 2</td>' +
    '<td>Data 3</td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>Data 1</td>' +
    '<td>Data 2</td>' +
    '<td>Data 3</td>' +
  '</tr>' 
};
```

Comment: This answer may be correct, but it is not obvious why. If you can provide an explanation as well, it will be of more use to others who read your answer, and help them decide if it applies to their problem or not

Answer (score -1):

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute("id", "tbl");
            document.body.appendChild(div)
                document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = "<table border = '1'>" +
              '<tr>' +
                '<th>Header 1</th>' +
                '<th>Header 2</th> ' +
                '<th>Header 3</th>' +
              '</tr>' +
              '<tr>' +
                '<td>Data 1</td>' +
                '<td>Data 2</td>' +
                '<td>Data 3</td>' +
              '</tr>' +
              '<tr>' +
                '<td>Data 1</td>' +
                '<td>Data 2</td>' +
                '<td>Data 3</td>' +
              '</tr>' +
              '<tr>' +
                '<td>Data 1</td>' +
                '<td>Data 2</td>' +
                '<td>Data 3</td>' +
              '</tr>'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of drawing a table using raphael.js.
We can draw tables directly to the canvas of the browser using Raphael.js
Raphael.js is a javascript library designed specifically for artists and graphic designers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='panel'></div>
    </body>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    
paper = new Raphael(0,0,500,500);// width:500px, height:500px

var x = 100;
var y = 50;
var height = 50
var width = 100;

WriteTableRow(x,y,width*2,height,paper,"TOP Title");// draw a table header as merged cell
y= y+height;
WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,"Score,Player");// draw table header as individual cells
y= y+height;
for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
var k;
k = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + 1 - 5) + 5);//prepare table contents as random data
WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,i+","+ k + "");// draw a row
y= y+height;
}


function WriteTableRow(x,y,width,height,paper,TDdata)
{ // width:cell width, height:cell height, paper: canvas, TDdata: texts for a row. Separated each cell content with a comma.

    var TD = TDdata.split(",");
    for (j=0;j<TD.length;j++)
    {
        var rect = paper.rect(x,y,width,height).attr({"fill":"white","stroke":"red"});// draw outline
        paper.text(x+width/2, y+height/2, TD[j]) ;// draw cell text
        x = x + width;
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Please check the preview image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAFhH.png

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer! Also, don't forget to check this: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I have added detailed explanations for the code.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function creatTable(row = 10, col = 6) {
  var table = "<table style ='margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; border-collapse: collapse; width: 70%; ' >";
  document.write(table);

  for (var h = 1; h < parseInt(col); h++) {

    th = "<th style='border: 3px solid #ddd;padding: 8px; padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 12px;text-align: center;background-color: #f5cf78;color: white;'>" + "I\'m Header";
    document.write(th);

    th += "</th>";

  }

  for (var i = 1; i < parseInt(row); i++) {

    tr = "<tr style='background: ; :hover{background: #ffff99}'>";
    document.write(tr);

    tr += "</tr>";

    for (var j = 1; j < parseInt(col); j++) {

      td = "<td style='border: 3px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;'>" + "I\'m cell no." + i + "," + j;
      document.write(td);

      td += "</td>";

    }

    tr += "</tr>";
  }

  table = "</table>";

}

console.log(creatTable())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>JavaScript...</h1>
  <h2>Hello!</h2>
  <h3>This Table Created by JavaScript &copy;
    <font color=# ff0026>Geologist / Mohamed Yasser</font>
  </h3>




  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

You might find this very helpful

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>tABLE IN JS</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <table border = "1">
     <tr>
        <th>Plug-in Name</th>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Description</th>
     </tr>
     
     <script language = "JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
        for (i = 0; i<3; i++) {
           document.write("<tr><td>");
           document.write("Hello world");
           document.write("</td><td>");
           document.write("Hello China");
           document.write("</td><td>");
           document.write("Hello USA");
           document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
     </script>
  </table>      
 </body>
</html>
```

So you create the table head according to the number of columns you want and the rows will depend on the number you specified in the iteration..... **i.e this one will be 3.**