# How to correctly make a table inside a table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created ten separate tables in javascript using HTML tags.  I now want to put those tables in a grid format so I thought putting them into another table would work.  This code just makes an empty table appear.  Any help?  Thanks!

```
 document.getElementById('InstalledApps').innerHTML += '<table id="bigAppsTable" border="1"><td>';

    for (var i = 9; i>-1;i--){  
        document.getElementById('InstalledApps').innerHTML += '<table id="appsTable'+i+'" border="1"><tr></tr>';

        var thirdRow=document.getElementById("appsTable"+i).insertRow(1);
        if (the_data[i]['release'] != null){
        thirdRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="<b>Release: ";
        thirdRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML=the_data[i]['release'];
        }
        var secondRow=document.getElementById("appsTable"+i).insertRow(1);
        secondRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="<b>Version: ";
        secondRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML=the_data[i]['version'];

        var firstRow=document.getElementById("appsTable"+i).insertRow(1);
        firstRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="<b>Name:";
        firstRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML=the_data[i]['name'];

        }
```

Comment: why you're not usiong `+=` here : `thirdRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML=the_data[i]['release'];` ?

Comment: your bigAppsTable table doesn't have any row

Comment: might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript

Comment: Because it's a separate cell, so there's nothing there anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dynamically creating tables, why not use the DOM API? (ie. not `innerHTML`)

Here is a good place to get your started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var aTable = document.createElement('table');

for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < 9; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some text"));
    tr.appendChild(td);
    aTable.appendChild(tr);
}

//update with id
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(aTable);
```

Comment: After running that code, it says on the last line that the element is null...?

Comment: make sure you are correct id with respect to your real div or table ids. in above mentioned code i defined example id etc.