# Json data to table javaScript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having Json data

```
var schedule = [
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Chasing", team1Score: "13", team2: "Amsterdam Money Gang", team2Score: "9"},
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Boomsquad", team1Score: "15", team2: "Beast Amsterdam", team2Score: "11"},
];
```

Now i need to add it to the following table with only the use of javaScript (**so no Jquery**, but  we can use micro libraries)

```
 <tr>
     <td data-bind="date"></td>
     <td data-bind="team1"></td>
     <td data-bind="team1score"></td>
     <td data-bind="team2"></td>
     <td data-bind="team2score"></td>
 </tr>
```

I was using the following to loop through the array, only now i don't know how to make a new tr on every array row

```
var len = schedule.length; 

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {

}
```

so i'm trying to get the following output

```
                <tr>
                    <td>Monday, 9:00am</td>
                    <td class="winner">Chasing</td>
                    <td>13 - 9</td>
                    <td>Amsterdam Money Gang</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Monday, 9:00am</td>
                    <td class="winner">Boomsquad</td>
                    <td>15 - 11</td>
                    <td>Beast Amsterdam</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Do you not know about `document.createElement()`? Have fun. And you spelled `length` wrong.

Comment: Why not use something like knockout.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UP9PV/1/)

You can do what you want this way:

```
var len = schedule.length;
var table = document.getElementById('table1');

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var s = schedule[i];

    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.date;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team1Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = s.team2Score;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you may have to adjust it based on your HTML layout.

```
var schedule = [
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Chasing", team1Score: "13", team2: "Amsterdam Money     Gang", team2Score: "9"},
{ date: "Monday, 9:00am", team1: "Boomsquad", team1Score: "15", team2: "Beast Amsterdam", team2Score: "11"},
];

document.write('<table>');
for(var i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++)
{
    var obj = schedule[i];

    document.write('<tr><td>' + obj.date + '</td><td class="winner">' + obj.team1 + '</td><td>' + obj.team1Score + ' - ' + obj.team2Score + '</td><td>' + obj.team2 + '</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: Using document.write to add elements to the DOM is not wise.
Adding new elements to the DOM should be only with createElement

Comment: I agree with you, createElement is a better choice. I was just trying to give a working sample, which can be easily modified to go with createElement.

Answer (score 0):

On every new array you should create a new TR element
Please look at the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript)