# how to display answers of form fill in inside a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question, we were required to do a form fill in which must contain a user name, first name, last name, and gender, what should i do for the inputted values to be displayed inside a table after pressing a button?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function myfunction() {
var fn = document.form1.firstname;
var ln = document.form1.lastname;
var un= document.form1.unsername;
var g = document.form1.gender;

first = first + fn.getElementById("firstname").value;
last = last + ln.getElementById("lastname").value;
user = user + un.getElementById("username").value;
gend= gend + g.getElementById("gender").value;

document.getElementById("displayhere").innerHTML;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="formname">
first name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
gender: <input type="text" id="gender">
username: <input type="text" id="username">
<button onclick="myfunction()">Send</button>
</form>

Details:

<table>
<tr><td><p id="displayhere"></p></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried to do? - note: you have repeated `id`'s attributes, which is not allowed

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
first name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br/>
last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br/>
gender: <input type="text" name="gender"><br/>
username: <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
<button onclick="return show(this.form)">Send</button>
</form>

Details:

<table>
<tr><td><p id="displayhere"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
function show(frm) {
   var str = "";
    str += "First Name : " + frm.firstname.value + "<br/>";
    str += "Last Name : " + frm.lastname.value + "<br/>";
    str += "Gender : " + frm.gender.value + "<br/>";
    str += "Username : " + frm.username.value + "<br/>";
    document.getElementById('displayhere').innerHTML = str
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would also like an alert to happen whenever the inputted for the gender is anything except f or m (I only want them to input f or m and if they input let's say 'a', then an alert message will show and not display the gender until the input is correct) what should I add in the code you have given for it to happen?

Comment: Add this `gender: <input type="text" name="gender" onkeyup="if(this.value!='f' && this.value!='m')this.value='';"><br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `rel` attribute to each of the input fields. In that, give the id of the `td` element in which you want the value of that input field to be inserted. For example, in your form, do this:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" rel="#firstname_td">
```

and in your table, do this:

```
<tr>
<td id="firstname_td">
```

Now, using jquery, on click event of that button (say, 'my_button'), call this:

```
$('#my_button').on("click",function()
{
 $("input[type=text]").each(function()
{
 id=$(this).attr('id');
 $(id).text($(this).val())
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First  chnage your id of gender and user name then Create a javascript function and get values from each text box append it to the p tag uisng innerHTML property

```
first name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
gender: <input type="text" id="gender">
username: <input type="text" id="username">
<button onclick="function1()">Send</button>

Details:

<table>
<tr><td><p id="displayhere"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
function function1(){

        var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;
        var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
        var result="First Name: "+firstname+"<br>Last Name:"+lastname+"<br>Gender : "+gender+"<br>User Name:"+username
        document.getElementById("displayhere").innerHTML=result;
    }

    </script>
```