# Displaying a table object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am filling an html table with *Javascript* arrays. But I am unable to display this table on the page. What can I do to display this table? Also, let me know if anything is wrong with my function.

Here is my code

```
function resultTable(arr1, arr2, arr3) {

    var result = "<table id='Result' border=1>";


    result += "<tr>";
    result += "<th>"+Name+"</th>";
    result += "<th>"+Score+"</th>";
    result += "<th>"+Grade+"</th>";
        result += "</tr>";

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+arr1[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr2[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr3[i]+"</td>";
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";

    return result;
}

var table = resultTable(names, score, grade);
```

Comment: set a div and sets the div inner html to return value of the fn

Comment: @shakeelosmani Got it, thanks!

Comment: I think your question might be duplicated of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript they provided a wide range of answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to apply the result to the DOM, for example, you can create specific container for that:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = table;
```

or just insert it into the `body`:

```
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

Here is an example:

```js
function resultTable(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    var result = "<table id='Result' border=1>";
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+arr1[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr2[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr3[i]+"</td>";
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";
    return result;
}

var names = ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3'];
var score = ['score 1', 'score 2', 'score 3'];
var grade = ['grade 1', 'grade 2', 'grade 3'];

var table = resultTable(names, score, grade);
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything's good here. All you need to now do is append it to DOM.
eg:

```
document.body.innerHTML = table
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v3z91rnk/)'s a working fiddle of that.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I added headers of the table, but it stopped working. I updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: You seem to have a string concatenation error in your updated code, `"<th>"+Name+"</th>"` should be simply `"<th>Name</th>"`, no string concatenation is required here. Do the same for *Score* and *Grade*.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM result element doesnt exist actually... It must be in the HTML or create via JavaScript.

Here in your example, it is only a string.

```js
function resultTable(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    
    // This is a string
    var result = "<table id='Result' border=1>";
    
    for(var i=0; i<1; i++) {
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<td>"+arr1[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr2[i]+"</td>";
        result += "<td>"+arr3[i]+"</td>";
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    
    result += "</table>";
    
    console.log( typeof result ); // string
    
    // Still a string
    return result;
}

// Still a string
var table = resultTable( [ 'Name' ], [ 'Score' ], [ 'Grade' ] );

console.log( typeof table ); // string

// You can add it via innerHTML like this :
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is alright you have to append a DOM element to it