# How do you create multiple table on a page with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to create empty tables on my page with a `Create table` button, but can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried looking some stuff up, but most of the things I see on tables just have you making a table in your html file instead of one being created with a button.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I don't have any code yet, i'm just trying to figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
You need to explain your issue in detail. Maybe add some code or add a graphical representation of the problem that will help users to understand.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how you create an empty `table` element. Please note that without any content and/or dimensions your table will not display anything (which is why I added the CSS part).

If that is not what you consider an *empty table*, **please be more specific in your requirements.**

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  document.body.appendChild(table);
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 4px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Create an empty table</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't do this with pure HTML, because HTML is just a markup language.

Do you know anything about Javascript?  You'll probably want to hook an `onclick` handler to the button.  You'll need the handler to [create a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript) and insert it into the correct location in the DOM.

Comment: This should be a comment.