# Javascript Start time from SQL value in table

Tags: javascript, sql, time

I am a bit lost at where to start I created a html page with users and clock in and clock out values displayed in a table. I want to write a script which continues a timer from clock in and stops at clock out. I am a really rusty with javascript

Comment: What's your progress so far?

Comment: You need to describe your scenario in greater detail. You've tagged your question with sql. Are the time in and time out values stored in a database? Will you need to write both backend and frontend (javascript) code?

Comment: @mortb   I created a table with the rows names, punch in , punch out , time spent. I have the rows punch in and punch out working perfectly but the time spent is where I want the timer to be I tried timestampdiff in sql but it will only work if the two values punch in and out exist(that was the reason I created time spent row ). What I want i the time should start from when the user punched in and stop when the person punched out please

Comment: @IamL I am done with everything is just left with the script for the time spent  so it displays on the html table.

Comment: @anony12: If you are using MySQL you could use the function `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` as input to the `timestampdiff` function. That will get you the difference between now and checkin time

Comment: This answer would tell you how to create a html table using javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript

Comment: Be sure to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask