# JS table generator with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript) on Stackoverflow and used it as a base for my own code which I will put below for you to check out.

I was just trying to get the buttons to render within the table but it just came up as plain text and not rendering as an HTML element on the page which is what I expected to happen with it.

**Here's the code that was using here for a reference point:**

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var btn = "<button>" + j +"-"+i+"</button>"
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(btn);

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function cell_id(x,y){
  msg('x:'+x+ ' y:'+y)
}
```

Does anyone know what solutions that you do to get it working the way I want it too? All help is appreciated.

Comment: createTextNode <-- what does that sound like what it does?

Comment: i get the problem now i look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createTextNode()` creates a text node, as the name says. If you have markup in it, it will be shown literally.

You should have created a `button` node, and set its text to the variables like this example below.

```js
    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerText = j + "-" + i;
      cell.appendChild(btn);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
```

Comment: `createElemebt`

Comment: Thanks, I must have had a shot of Novacaine when I was coding that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a button node and then append it.

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var button document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = j +"-"+i;
      cell.appendChild(button);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function cell_id(x,y){
  msg('x:'+x+ ' y:'+y)
}
```