# js button generator with functions

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, button

I got the code to generate the table with buttons i wanted,
but i also want to get a `"onlick="cell_id(" + j +"," + i ")"` function within the `<button>` element using js.

The `j` and `i` variables are to mark the row and column where the click came from and also used to create the table.

**the code:**

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = j +"-"+i;
      cell.appendChild(button);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function cell_id(x,y){
  window.alert('x:'+x+ ' y:'+y)
}
```

code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61549235/12825970

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: @VLAZ i need help with using js to get a function in a button element

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem/question is, but I have a feeling you might be looking for [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: ```button.addEventListener('onclick')``` track the button sense it has no id or anything to id it form the rest of the buttons

Comment: `cellIndex` on table cell elements and `rowIndex` on table row elements exist. So this whole thing can be done by adding _one_ click handler to the table, checking if the event target was a `button`, and if so going up to the parent cell and row, and getting the respective index values from there - https://jsfiddle.net/7vdLekz2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a listener to each button element:

```
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = j +"-"+i;
      setupListener(button);
      cell.appendChild(button);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function setupListener(button, i, j) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    cell_id(button, i, j);
  });
}

function cell_id(button, x, y){
  msg('x:'+x+ ' y:'+y)
}
```

This approach works, but is expensive if you have a lot of buttons. For a more advanced approach, you can store the `i` and `j` as `data` attributes on the button, then use a single click event on the entire table. You can filter the events to check if they came from a "source" button. I'll leave that up to you if it's an option you want to pursue.

Comment: can it track the button it came from, its important for what im using it for

Comment: Updated the post to also pass the button.