# Grid & Dynamic Table's Height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, grid

I have a table that is created dynamically using Javascript / jQuery. The logic of which can be seen below:

```
$.each(input, function (key, value){

    let parent = $('<tr>');
    let container = $('<td>').text('Test');
    parent.append(container);
    table.append(parent);
 
});
```

Before I began creating the table dynamically I was able to have both a header and footer remain in view while having the table scroll when its height became too large. I did this with the following:

```
//HTML
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

     <div id="header"></div>
     <table id="content"></table>
     <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>
</body>

//CSS
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr 100px;
}

#content {
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Although now, with the dynamic table, neither my header nor my footer will stay in view while scrolling.

To attempt to fix this I tried resetting the CSS once my page was loaded but this was unsuccessful. How can I created a fixed/sticky header & footer while still keeping my table dynamic?

Edit: I am looking for a solution that doesn't require setting a static height for the table.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549116/js-table-generator-with-buttons) to answer your question?

Comment: Where is your input ?

Comment: @Ajith Sorry but I dont see how that is relevant to the question. Its simply an associative array.

Comment: @Newb4YouBB no issues.  Just one question , So you need table height to be fixed for example total height is 100 px Head  and footer10px then no matter what the content in table body grows, height of body should be 80 px eith scroll isnt it?

Comment: @Ajith exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS Only Solution**

@Ajith's answer was good but I wanted to share the solution I will be using.

**Notice** If you have issues using this solution with MS Edge, your edge version may need to be updated.

First, I realized I had no `<div>` surrounding my table. Therefore the `overflow` would not work correctly. So I created an element around the table called `table-container`.

Second, all we need to do is add `height : 100%` to our `table-container` CSS.

```
//HTML
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

     <div id="header"></div>
     <div id="table-container">
         <table id="content"></table>
     </div>
     <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>
</body>

//CSS
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr 100px;
}

#table-container {
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: auto;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```js
var table = $("#content");

var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

$.each(input, function (key, value){

    let parent = $('<tr>');
    let container = $('<td>').text('Test');
    parent.append(container);
    table.append(parent);
 
});

var addRow = function(){
    let parent = $('<tr>');
    let container = $('<td>').text('Test');
    parent.append(container);
    table.append(parent);    
}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr 30px;
}

#table-container {
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: auto;
   height: 100%;
}

#header, #footer{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

     <div id="header">
        <button onclick="addRow()">Add Data</button>
     </div>
     <div id="table-container">
         <table id="content"></table>
     </div>
     <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try my below code , You should set height after rendering the innerhtml

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JS Code</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<style>
//CSS
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 56px 1fr 100px;
}
.fixed{height::100px;
overflow:scroll;}

#content {

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

     <div id="header"></div>
     <table id="content" width="150px" border="1">
     <thead>
        <tr><th>Head</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="fixed">
                <table  id="mybody"></table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tfoot>
        <tr><th>Foot</th></tr>
     </tfoot>
     </table>
     <div id="footer"></div>

  </div>
</body>
<script>
const arr=[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18];

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var table = $("#mybody");
     $.each(arr, function (key, value){

        let parent = $('<tr>');
        let container = $('<td>').text('Test');
        parent.append(container);
        table.append(parent);
     
    });
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        table.parent().css({"height":"100px"});
    },100);
    
    
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require setting a static height for the table.

Comment: @Newb4YouBB You can apply some logic there , It is upto you

Comment: thank you again for your answer. While it wasnt the solution I ended up choosing, it did help me discover my solution.

Comment: @Newb4YouBB Please do support me if it helps you