# How to create on click events(button) for child rows in Datatables

Tags: javascript

I need to create fields dynamically in child table using JavaScript based on a value entered by a user.

eg. if the user enters 5 then 5 fields has to be created newly. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but have you tried anything? If yes then please share your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create table using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript)

Comment: No i haven't tried anything specifically. I need to create fields where there is row already.