# Create a html table where inputs are inside <td>

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I have the following html table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
      <td> <input> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Instead, I would like to create this table **only with javascript**. I have read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript). However, I would like that inside every `<td>` there is an `<input>` (as shown on the code provided). Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

function generateTable() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const row = table.insertRow();
    for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
      const cell = row.insertCell();
      const inputCell = document.createElement("INPUT");
      cell.appendChild(inputCell);
    }
  }
}

generateTable()
```

```html
<table> </table>
```